# Ncurses output functions only accept const data

Tags: c++, file, c++11, stream, ncurses

I'm trying to add strings to the window while `getline()` is getting lines from the opened text file. Using ncurses and c++, I am doing the following:

```
string line;                     //String to hold content of file and be printed
ifstream file;                   //Input file stream
file.open(fileName)              //Opens file fileName (provided by function param)

if(file.is_open()) {             //Enters if able to open file                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  while(getline(file, line)) {   //Runs until all lines in file are extracted via ifstream                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  addstr(line);                  //LINE THAT ISN'T WORKING                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  refresh();                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  file.close();                    //Done with the file                                                                                                                                                                                                 
}
```

**So my question is**... what am I supposed to do in ncurses if I want to output something that isn't a const data type? None of the output functions I see [in the documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printw) accept anything [but const input](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/printw.html).
It should be noted that this program works perfectly fine if I am just outputting the content of the file to the console, so that removes the possibility of it being a file reading/opening error or something with the stream. The exact error I get on compilation is:

> error: cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘int waddnstr(WINDOW*, const char*, int)’
>          addstr(line);

Let me know if you need any more info.

**EDIT:** Added links to relevant documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem doesn't have anything to do with `const`ness, or non-`const`ness of anything, directly.

The problem is that ncurses' `addstr()` is a C library function, that expects a null-terminated C style string.

You are attempting to pass, as an argument, a C++ `std::string` object, to `addstr`(). Given that `addstr`() itself is a C library function, this is not going to end very well.

The solution is to use `std::string`'s `c_str`() method to get a C-style string.

```
addstr(line.c_str());
```

Comment: I think we're getting closer. That solved the compilation error, but now it doesn't output the text. Can I do something to provide you with more info?

Comment: No, this answers the question that asked. If you want to ask something else, that would be a new question. Be sure to provide an [mcve] in your question. The code that was shown in this question fails to meet the requirements of a [mcve].